# Laptop fan always on with AC, not always on with battery, despite being configured

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, power-management, fan

My laptop occasionally gets somewhat hot, so I've configured my power plan in Windows 7 so that the fan should always be on whether powered by AC or battery.

However the fans don't always run when the system is battery-powered, only seeming to be on when the system wants (or when there is AC power). Is there another setting I need to change to get this to work?

/It`s a HP 625 notebook.

Comment: Laptop... what laptop? Manufacturer? Model?

Answer (score 1):

Windows actually specifies two methods of cooling policy: Active and passive. To go to this screen, Choose power options (in control panel) -> change plan settings -> change advanced power settings.

[image]

Active means the fan speed is increased before decreasing the processor state.
Passive means the processor state is decreased before increasing fan speed.

Occasionally, program like "thinkpad fan control" and "aa1fancontrol" (for thinkpad and acer aspire one respectively) exists. Usually these are due to having enough hackers using these laptops but the reason behind is usually due to the fan being too noisy. <p flamebait="1"> I doubt, that there are currently enough hackers using HP to get this done... </p>

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is probably not.

Most fans are actually controlled the the system BIOS. There is a temperature sensor on the CPU that reports to the BIOS and it controls the speed of the fan. If the manufacture designed the BIOS to ignore fan speed control commands from windows, your power settings will have no affect on the fan control.

I would look around the BIOS and see if there are any settings that control power, hardware, or CPU clocking. That is the only place I can think of where you could enable fan control. Knowing HP, they probably hide that from you so you can have a better "customer experience".

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Doltknuckle regarding the fans. You could try to play around with your power management settings a bit more (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/power-management), though if it is an issue, you could get a cooling pad.